# how to make both vscode and JetBrains have the same protobuf formatter

Tags: protocol-buffers

Our project team members are using both vscode and JetBrains editors.
All of us are writing protobuf files, but there's a difference in formatters between vscode and JetBrains.

We want to standardize the formatting rules to match JetBrains' conventions.
In vscode, we are using the vscode-proto3 extension along with the clang-format plugin.

We are unsure about the settings in JetBrains, and we need guidance on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote as below.

vscode/.settings.json

`{ "clang-format.style": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, ColumnLimit: 0 }" }`

and then it became the same format.

this solved it.